# Start service after all http handling services have started

Tags: server, services, nodejs

I have been puzzling over this one for a while now and I have managed to refine my issue to one problem. I have a service which is supposed to run a shell script to start daemon processes (using nohup), these processes are discord bots written using nodejs and discordjs. Currently I have a service that starts the test discord bot when I run it using `sudo systemctl start startdiscordbots` and that works fine. The issue is when I restart the computer the service throws the error below:

```
/daemons/discordbots/discounter/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:172
Aug 31 13:35:15 ubuntu start.sh[2459]:         throw new HTTPError(error.message, error.constructor.name, error.status, request);
Aug 31 13:35:15 ubuntu start.sh[2459]:               ^
Aug 31 13:35:15 ubuntu start.sh[2459]: HTTPError [FetchError]: request to https://discord.com/api/v9/gateway/bot failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN discord.com
Aug 31 13:35:15 ubuntu start.sh[2459]:     at RequestHandler.execute (/daemons/discordbots/discounter/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:172:15)
Aug 31 13:35:15 ubuntu start.sh[2459]:     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Aug 31 13:35:15 ubuntu start.sh[2459]:     at async RequestHandler.push (/daemons/discordbots/discounter/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:14)
Aug 31 13:35:15 ubuntu start.sh[2459]:     at async WebSocketManager.connect (/daemons/discordbots/discounter/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:128:9)
Aug 31 13:35:15 ubuntu start.sh[2459]:     at async Client.login (/daemons/discordbots/discounter/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:245:7) {
Aug 31 13:35:15 ubuntu start.sh[2459]:   code: 500,
Aug 31 13:35:15 ubuntu start.sh[2459]:   method: 'get',
Aug 31 13:35:15 ubuntu start.sh[2459]:   path: '/gateway/bot',
Aug 31 13:35:15 ubuntu start.sh[2459]:   requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
Aug 31 13:35:15 ubuntu start.sh[2459]: }
```

So I know that the service starts fine once all other services have been loaded correctly but I am guessing that there is a service that I need to put in the `After=` part of the startdiscordbots.service file that I have missed, my `startdiscordbots.service` code is below

```
[Unit]
Description=Start discord bots as background processes

After=network.target systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/startup/start.sh
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
KillMode=process
User=ubuntu

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Does anyone know if there is a service that I need to specify in the `After=` that I have missed or is there something else going on?

The computer I am using is a RaspberryPi with Ubuntu Server installed, I am using node v16.8.0 and npm v7.21.0 with discordjs v13.1.0. I only have access to the terminal so please don't give answers telling me to use other tools.

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: You're looking at the wrong thing, it's not a service.  You want to wait until network connectivity is established. Only then, you can reach things across the network.

Comment: @waltinator How would I go about doing that? I seem to have come up with a solution (by adding `After=multi-user.target`) but I'm not sure how long it will last...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function that blocks until network is up, makes other tests (is there a `default` route (`man ip ip-route`), can you `host google.com` (`man host`), etc., then starts your services. I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect. A little `bash` knowledge will let you modify this. Read `man bash`.